# Remote Desktop not working after Windows Update

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

I've updated Windows recently on my Windows Server 2019 Standard, 1809. Since then, Remote Desktop is not working anymore. I can connect, but then the screen stays either black or it shows an improper image, like the following. But the login text boxes never appear. Since this incident I work with VNC. But it would be great if Remote Desktop could work again!

[image: Screen image error after connecting with RDP]

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the machine?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, many times.

Comment: Possibly you might wish to consider running DISM and SFC.  These should run on a Server but I am not certain.  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: The server has installed more updates and rebooted over night. Now suddenly, magically Remote Desktop works again, after several weeks! I just hope it doesn't break it again, with future updates...
Thanks for the suggestions though, I will come back to these in case it will stop working again.

Answer (score 1):

Run Group Policy Editor.  Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administration Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Connection Client.  Set the "Turn Off UDP On Client" setting to Enabled.

Try connection again in MSTSC. Should work OK.  No reboot required.

Credits: [Bert](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/dff1a051-afa9-48e5-ba77-4c5cffd54634/issue-connecting-to-rdp-only-win10-1809-gt-windows-server-2019?forum=ws2019) (note that there are also some workarounds on that page).